# Rust + Rust Image - Private 'Associated Type'?

Tags: image, image-processing, types, rust, associated-types

The goal is simple - get the colour at (0, 0) and remove any pixels in the image that are similar to it within the specified threshold (16384 in this case). However, the code below doesn't compile:

```
#![feature(env, old_path, core, old_io)]

extern crate image;

use std::env;
use std::num::ToPrimitive;
use std::old_io::File;
use image::color::FromColor;

use image::Pixel;

fn get_arguments() -> Vec<String> {
  let mut argv: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
  argv.remove(0);
  return argv;
}

fn remove_background<T:image::GenericImage>(img: &mut T) {
  let background_color = img.get_pixel(0, 0).to_rgba();

  let transparent_pixel = image::Rgba([0, 0, 0, 0]);

  if background_color[3].to_uint().unwrap() > 0 {
    for (x, y, color) in img.pixels() {

      let rgba = color.to_rgba();

      let (dr,dg,db) = (rgba[0] - background_color[0],
                        rgba[1] - background_color[1],
                        rgba[2] - background_color[2]);

      if (dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db).to_uint().unwrap() < 16384 { img.put_pixel(x, y, transparent_pixel); } // Remove the background colour.

    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  for filepath in get_arguments() {
    let img = image::open( &Path::new(filepath) ).unwrap();

    remove_background( &mut img );


    let ref mut fout = File::create(&Path::new("output.png")).unwrap();
    img.save(fout, image::PNG);
  }
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
src/main.rs:32:83: 32:100 error: mismatched types:
 expected `<T as image::image::GenericImage>::Pixel`,
    found `image::color::Rgba<_>`
(expected associated type,
    found struct `image::color::Rgba`) [E0308]
src/main.rs:32       if (dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db).to_uint().unwrap() < 16384 { img.put_pixel(x, y, transparent_pixel); } // Remove the background colour.
```

This is presumably because the GenericImage struct defines its own internal "Pixel", which I don't think I can access, but is exactly the same as the normal Pixel struct. How would I get code with this functionality to compile? Every other use of `put_pixel` I've seen has used `get_pixel` on the image object and manipulated that, but I need to use a transparent pixel, so that won't work.

Comment: A type implementing `GenericImage` specifies a particular type for `Pixel` which I presume the `put_pixel` method takes; you, however, have given it an `Rgba`, which is not necessarily the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Morgan is spot on - when you are accepting a `GenericImage`, you have to handle a generic `Pixel`. However, you are trying to use a specific one - `Rgba`. Even more than that, you have to specify the type of the channels of the `Rgba`.

A notable issue with your original code is: what do you do when the GenericImage is composed of pixels that *don't support transparency*?

Here's a version that picks some concrete types and compiles:

```
fn remove_background<T>(img: &mut T)
    where T: image::GenericImage<Pixel=image::Rgba<u8>>
{
    let background_color = img.get_pixel(0, 0).to_rgba();

    if background_color[3].to_uint().unwrap() > 0 {
        for (_, _, color) in img.pixels_mut() {

            let rgba = color.to_rgba();

            let (dr,dg,db) = (rgba[0] - background_color[0],
                              rgba[1] - background_color[1],
                              rgba[2] - background_color[2]);

            // Remove the background colour.
            if (dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db).to_uint().unwrap() < 16384 {
                for c in color.channels_mut().iter_mut() { *c = 0 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beyond specifying the specific pixel type in the `where` clause, you'll also run into mutability issues. I changed it to `pixels_mut`, `channels_mut`, and `iter_mut` to get the mutability to the right place.

Note that the Rust style is 4-space indents, so I've done that as well.